# Where to put downloadable csv file in custom module and generate download link in phtml?

Tags: magento2, csv, downloader, download-link

I have a **csv** file, i want to put it inside my custom module folder `app/code/Vendor/Module` but i don't know where to put the csv file inside my custom extension folder, and how to generate link to download this **csv** file, so i can put the download link inside my `a href` tag in **frontend phtml**

Comment: Put your csv files under the folder app/code/Vendor/Files/Sample/

Comment: are you need file download link admin side or frontend side?

Comment: @Abdul frontend side

Comment: You can put files in pub/media as well. So you can generate url for pub/media and put them in the href tag.

Comment: @nortonuser Please let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: have you got solution?

Answer (score 3):

**You need to create csv folder inside your area(frontend/adminhtml)**

```
app/code/{Namespace}/{Modulename}/view/{area}/web/csv/en_US.csv
```

call directly inside template files,

```
echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Namespace_Modulename::csv/en_US.csv');
```